# Variable visibility in NodeJS and ES6 Class instances

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to refactor a large JS codebase from a single file into multiple classes in multiple files. I can't access variables that I think I should be able to access. I must be misunderstanding something about javascript objects / NodeJS modules / exports / imports / referencing 'this'.

Before I started, everything was in file ai.js inside block `module.exports = function Ai() { ...`

I created file **heatMap.js** according to EcmaScript 6 Class syntax:

```
module.exports = HeatMap;
class HeatMap {
    constructor(ai, ...) {
        this.ai = ai;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I modified **ai.js** to import the HeatMap class, instantiate it, and pass the object a reference to the ai object so that the heatmap could access its variables.

```
const HeatMap = require("heatMap.js");
module.exports = function Ai() {
    var ai = this;
    var currentRound = ...
    ...
    function bookKeeping(...) {
        heatMap = new HeatMap(ai,...);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Trying to access currentRound inside heatMap with `this.ai.currentRound` yields:

> Unresolved variable currentRound.

Why? "This" should reference the instantiated heatMap object, "ai" should reference the ai object, and the ai object has variable currentRound. One way to make this work would be passing all variables as parameters in function calls, but there's a lot of them, so it wouldn't be a clean solution.

Comment: *""ai" should reference the ai object"* but does this object have a property `currentRound`? All your doing in your example is create a *local variable* `currentRound`, not a property. Maybe you intended to do `this.currentRound = ... `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the `HeatMap` definition:

```
module.exports = HeatMap;

function HeatMap(ai) {
  console.log(ai.currentRound);
}
```

And the `AI` definition:

```
module.exports = AI;
const HeatMap = require('HeatMap');

function AI() {
  this.currentRound = 0;
}

AI.prototype.bookKeeping = function bookKeeping() {
  const heatMap = new HeatMap(this);
}
```

You should see `0` printed on invoking `bookKeeping()` from an instance of `AI`.

I don't use ES2015 classes, but from what I see, your scope is wrong. Your `currentRound` variable is locally scoped to the `AI` function and is not exposed in any way (in the snippet you provided). Thus, when you pass an instance of `AI` into `HeatMap` `currentRound` is available to the methods exposed by the `AI` constructor, but not to the `HeatMap` function itself.